# Can not established postgres connection using prisma in-between nodes inside kubernets cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, prisma

I am able to established connection from other pods running psql cli by using below command.

```
PGPASSWORD=root psql -h postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgresdb
```

but unable from inside code.

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = "postgresql://postgres:root@postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:5432/postgresdb?schema=public"
}
```

when I run  **npx prisma introspect** it's throw below error

```
Error: P1001

Can't reach database server at `postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local`:`5432`.
```

Comment: I am able to connect using cluster IP addres and node port service: postgresql://postgres:root@192.168.49.2:30432/postgresdb?schema=public"

Comment: Where do you run this code? And `npx prisma introspect`? DNS name is accessible only within kubernetes cluster and specified `namespace`. If you want to test anything on your local machine, you can add this dns name to `/etc/hosts` with service cluster-IP